# Python program: foreign language word-frequency dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to build a simple program which takes a text file, builds a `dict()` with the words as keys, and the values as the number of times each word appears (word frequency).

I've learned that the `collections.Counter` function can do this easily (among other methods). My problem is that, I'd like the dictionary to be ordered by the frequency so that I can print the Nth most frequent words. Finally, I also need to have a way for the dictionary to later associate a value of a different type (string of the definition of the word).

Basically I need something that outputs this:

```
Number of words: 5
[mostfrequentword: frequency, definition]
[2ndmostfrequentword: frequency, definition]
etc.
```

This is what I have so far, but it only counts the word frequency, I don't know how to order the dictionary by the frequency and then print the Nth most frequent words:

```
wordlist ={}

def cleanedup(string):
    alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    cleantext = ''
    for character in string.lower():
        if character in alphabet:
            cleantext += character
        else:
            cleantext += ' '
    return cleantext

def text_crunch(textfile):
       for line in textfile:
            for word in cleanedup(line).split():
                if word in wordlist:
                    wordlist[word] += 1
                else:
                    wordlist[word] = 1


with open ('DQ.txt') as doc:
    text_crunch(doc)
    print(wordlist['todos'])
```

Comment: You mention `Counter` but aren't using it - if you were the `most_common` method would come in handy.

Comment: Yeah, 30 secs after posting this I saw that method on the documentation. But I don't quite understand how it works (it looks like it will go through the whole text every time I run the program, I'd rather have a static dictionary that I can edit and add more keys (words) to.

Comment: right, `collections.Counter` or `nltk.FreqDist` would both do what you need- they both have a `most_common` method. eg `counter.most_common(5)` for the 5 most common

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is - `Counter` is a `dict` subclass, you can use it pretty much everywhere you use a vanilla dictionary. Also, what do you mean "static"?

Comment: Ah, now I see. I didn't know that Counter was a subclass of dict, all is clear now. Also, by "static" I meant that I want the dictionary to be made once and then subsequently accessed, instead of it being made on the fly every time I run the program (which takes a while for me). Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler version of your code that does pretty much what you want :)

```
import string
import collections

def cleanedup(fh):
    for line in fh:
        word = ''
        for character in line:
            if character in string.ascii_letters:
                word += character
            elif word:
                yield word
                word = ''

with open ('DQ.txt') as doc:
    wordlist = collections.Counter(cleanedup(doc))
    print wordlist.most_commond(5)
```

Alternative solutions with regular expressions:

```
import re
import collections

def cleandup(fh):
    for line in fh:
        for word in re.findall('[a-z]+', line.lower()):
            yield word

with open ('DQ.txt') as doc:
    wordlist = collections.Counter(cleanedup(doc))
    print wordlist.most_commond(5)
```

Or:

```
import re
import collections

def cleandup(fh):
    for line in fh:
        for word in re.split('[^a-z]+', line.lower()):
            yield word

with open ('DQ.txt') as doc:
    wordlist = collections.Counter(cleanedup(doc))
    print wordlist.most_commond(5)
```

Comment: Wow, this is great. Thanks so much! However, can I later add a "definition" value to the collection wordlist? (So that it eventually prints the word, its frequency, and it definition?)

Comment: I would keep the definitions (for simplicity) in a separate dictionary. Just print `definition[word]` in those cases :)

Comment: `import re` `collections.Counter(i.group(0).lower() for i in re.finditer(r'([A-Za-z]+)', doc))` should be more efficient and flexible that the `cleanedup` function @ShihabDider

Comment: @GP89: or even: `collections.Counter(re.split('[^a-zA-Z]', doc.read().lower()))`

Comment: Will the latter exclude '' as "words"? As it stands, if I do `most_common(0)` it will return `''` as the most frequent word

Comment: That's actually easily fixable with `elif word:` instead of `else:`

Comment: @Wolph nice, I was trying to get around having the whole list of matches in memory at once. But wasn't easy to read the file lazily in a comment so ended up using `read` anyway. yours is definitely preferable though. bonus points if you can do that ;)

Comment: @GP89: see the new versions :)